# How to click on a div in one html page and have it create a div in another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I found this code here that allows me to create a div element in a different section by clicking it, it works ok within the same html file as seen below in the fidle

http://jsfiddle.net/fb7Tq/109/

My problem is that i want to make this code work between different html files, how can I go about this??

in the first html I have the initial divs.

```
<div class="section1">
<div id="1" >1</div>
<div id="2" >2</div>
<div id="3" >3</div>
<div id="4" >4</div>
<div id="5" >5</div>
<div id="6" >6</div>
<div id="7" >7</div>
<div id="8" >8</div>
```

And then when those divs are clicked, they need to come up in a different html file within this div below.

```
<div class="section2"></div>
```

and here is the js

```
    function testclick() {
    var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.section2').append(this);
    $('#'+iLoc).off('click', testclick).bind('click',testclick2) ;
}

function testclick2() {

    var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.section1').append(this);
    this.off('click', testclick2).on('click',testclick) ;
}
$('.section1 div').on('click', testclick);
$('.section2 div').on('click', testclick2);
```

any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Where is the relationship between the different pages? Are they in different frames in the same page? Are they parent page and iframe? Are they in different tabs in the browser?

Comment: Is your "website" posted online, or is this project running on a local computer? If on a local computer, are you running a stack like XAMPP or WAMP/LAMP/MAMP? This is important info because the solution will be different depending what tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: they are different pages of one web project. .section1 is in the 'about.html' The .section2 is in the 'index.html' The html files themselves are linked by <a href> links between each other.  @OscarPaz

Comment: Local, Its a web app that will be compiled with phonegap. I am not using Wamp, I just use ripple to test the results. @gibberish

Comment: So, if you click a div in the first page, when will the modified div be modified? When the user loads it? You want the modification to affect the file in the hard disk or something like that?

Comment: Ok, if you know apps like Flipboard, Zite, users are able to click on a topic, (subscribing) then once that topic is clicked, its contents are seen on the home screen. The Divs in .section1 will contain a list of topics that a user can subscribe to by clicking, when they do this, .section2 will contain rss feeds with those topics they subscribed to on their home screen. @OscarPaz

Comment: You can do this more easily backwards, when clicking on an element, fetch a document and load into the element. Otherwise you will need to pass it as a cookie, or local storage, or get request parameter, and the next page would have to look for that parameter and react.

Answer (score 0):

By what say in your comments, what you need is a web application with server-side code. static html files won't serve. In the end, to achieve what you want, you'll have to send a request (directly or via AJAX) when a user clicks one of your divs, so the server 'saves', in some way, the user's preference and shows the modified page accordingly.

This is not a trivial problem, and certainly something that won't be achieved with a few lines of javascript. It's out of the scope of a question in StackOverflow to explain how to build a web application with server-side code.

**EDIT** I've read some of the other comments you posted. So you want to make an app with PhoneGap. Well, in that case, maybe you could do something else, using localStorage.

When the ser clicks the div, store the info about what the user selected using localStorage.setItem. LocalStorage is a persistent place to store objects between sessions. Then, the next time you open the page in which you want to display the div, you just read the value stored in localStorage (with localStorage.getItem()), and use the value to display the correct DIV.

More about localStorage here, in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). I hope this servers you. Just take into account that when the user opens the app in a differente device, none of these preferences will be set. Configuration will be stored in the device.

Comment: I see. I was hoping to find a way around that. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. @OscarPaz

Comment: I made an edit, maybe what I posted could serve you.